# Reduce image size using PhotosPickersItem and saving the image to core data

Tags: swift, image-processing, swiftui

I wonder if it is possible to upload an image using PhotosPickersItem and then reducing the image's file size before saving it to Core Data?

I have everything working with selecting and uploading an image and saving it to core data using binary data.

This is my code for the PhotosPickersItem:

```
            Section {
                VStack {
                    PhotosPicker("Select an Image", selection: $photoItem, matching: .any(of: [.images, .not(.livePhotos)]))
                    
                    if let image {
                        Image(uiImage: (UIImage(data: image)?.resizeWithWidth(width: 400)! ?? UIImage(systemName: "photo"))!)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                            
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: photoItem) { _ in
                    Task {
                        if let data = try? await photoItem?.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
                                image = data
                        }
                        print("Failed")
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you trying to reduce the image's dimensions or wanting to keep the dimensions but reduce the image file size?

Comment: I want to reduce the image file size. I know that there is a method for it when using UIImage, but I can't find a method when using PhotosPickersItem and Data-type

Comment: in SwiftUI it's `.task(id: photoItem)` not `Task {}`